# Trying to use a discord.py bot to send a link and then read the embed of that link

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that creates a random link that it then sends into the channel the user asked for it from, I then try to get it to read the embed of the link that it sends but no matter what I do it can't read the embed, if I send the same embed it can read it fine. It is embedding correctly when it sends the link, as I can see it but it can't detect an embed in the message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include a [mre]. Usually the link embeds should be automatic (unless you suppress them). How are you getting them? What is the output of `len(message.embeds)`?

Comment: The embeds are being generated as in I am able to see them, but I am unable to access them with the bot, the len of message.embeds is 0. I can add some code to the question tommorow because it's late right now.

Comment: Oh I've figured the issue out, I'm not entirely sure why it does this, but I was using a randint to generate part of the link so every link/embed was different, the first time it loads the embed the bot can't read it so I just print the message twice, 1 being delayed, and then delete the first message